# Using Alias with JSON_EXTRACT using a SELECT query

Tags: mysql, json

I gave each of my variables an alias in this select query. However when I try to give the JSON_EXTRACT an alias, I get an error.

```
SELECT  
    var1 'varName1',
    var2 'varName2',    
    JSON_EXTRACT(varJSON, '$.objectOne')
        FROM tableTwo w
        WHERE t.thisId = w.thatId
        'varName3'
FROM myTable t
//WHERE etc
```

Keeps getting a syntax error near `''varName3' FROM myTable t'`.

I searched but couldn't find any documentation on this specific problem. Is this possible to do?

Comment: This query is incorrect. Is it a correlated subquery? Please post your data and desired result https://dbfiddle.uk

Comment: @Lukasz Szozda What's incorrect about it?

Comment: `FROM tableTwo w
        WHERE t.thisId = w.thatId
        'varName3'
FROM myTable t` - there is no `()` indicating where subquery ends

Comment: Look for `SELECT  
    var1 'varName1',
    var2 'varName2',    
    JSON_EXTRACT(varJSON, '$.objectOne') FROM myTable t JOIN tableTwo w
        ON t.thisId = w.thatId WHERE (etc. conditions)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! The JSON_EXTRACT needs to have another SELECT and be wrapped in parentheses, then if the second table is joined, the query accepts it as a variable and allows the alias.

```
SELECT  
var1 'varName1',
var2 'varName2',    
(SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(w.varJSON, '$.objectOne')
    FROM tableTwo w
    WHERE t.thisId = w.thatId) 'aliasName3'
FROM myTable t
LEFT JOIN tableTwo w ON tableTwoID = myTableID
/*WHERE etc*/
```

In case it helps anyone else...